# Iframe on Google Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, iframe, web

Hello i am making a website but i am trying to iframe facebook or google into my website, but its not working no website link pops up, i am using google chrome.

http://mattscomputing.3owl.com/facebook.php

there is the link for you to test yourself.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" name="facebook" width="100%" height="600px">
</iframe>
```

that is the code i am using, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google sends a "x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN" response header, which disallows the browser from displaying an iFrame  of it outside of it's parent page.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, Facebook is even more strict about it. No iFrame, regardless of the parent page, may embed it (due to it's x-frame-options:DENY response header).

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't give you the answer you wanted.